# Facebook login: Show Activity after login

Tags: android, android-activity, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

currently I work with the `Facebook` SDK for `Android`. I programmed a `Facebook` login for my app like described in this official tutorial: [Facebook Login for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate). This works fine. The idea of this approach is that you have a Main `Activity` and two `Fragment`s (Login and Welcome Screen). One of these `Fragment`s is hidden - depending on if the user connected to `Facebook` succesfully.

I want to try a different approach: My welcome screen is a main `Activity` with a `Navigation Drawer` (which allows me to replace `Fragment`s depending on which menu item the user selects). If the user is not connected to `Facebook`, the login screen should be displayed. After login, the main `Activity` should be displayed (or rather one of the `Navigation Drawer` `Fragment`s) even when the user restarts the app.

What I could do: Implementing the two `Fragment` tutorial example as described above and offer a `Button` which starts a new activity - but I don't want to click always this `Button` when starting the app!

Are there any tutorials or do you have an idea how to realize that approach without implementing a welcome `Fragment` which is displayed before the user can see the main `Activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a working solution.

This code makes sure that you'll be forwarded to `MainActivity` and afterwards, the `LoginActivity` is removed from the back stack (back button closes the app).

Hwoever, there's still a problem: If I close the app, remove the app from my `Facebook` account and reinstall it, I'll be forwarded to `MainActivity` again and so I'm not forced to login again. If I close the app and open it again, the `LoginActivity` is displayed correctly.

If I debug this scenario, everythings works perfectly. How can I avoid this problem?

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean isResumed = false;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        isResumed = true;
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
        isResumed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (isResumed) {
            if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

}
```